# Stay at the same page after the form is submitted at the Joomla! back end

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I got a form inside the default.php of admin side of com_product. The problem is, the form redirects back to the control panel after submit. I need it to stay at the current page.
the form uses GET method and as the action, I've tried all these:

```
<form method="get" action="<?php echo $current_url; ?>">
...

$current_url = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] . '&' . $_GET['date_scope']; // Results: administrator/index.php?date_scope=1&submit_range=
```

and also:

```
$current_url = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; // Results: administrator/option=com_product&view=reports?date_scope=1&submit_range=
```

and also:

```
$current_url = JURI::root() . 'administrator/index.php?option=com_product?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] . $_GET['date_scope']; // Results: administrator/index.php?date_scope=1&submit_range=
```

and also:

```
$current_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // Results: administrator/index.php?date_scope=1&submit_range=
```

and also:

```
$current_url = JURI::root() . 'administrator/index.php?option=com_product'; // Reuslts: administrator/index.php?date_scope=1&submit_range=
```

and also:

```
$current_url = JURI::root() . 'administrator/index.php?option=com_product' . $_GET['date_scope']; //  Results: administrator/index.php?date_scope=1&submit_range=
```

Any idea how can be handled, so it stays at the same page after the form submission?

Comment: Anybody please?

Comment: give default.php and controller code that saves data.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't receive the answer on time. In any case, cause of this problem and for other reasons I used AJAX. The question is removed now and the answer will be used for the future if any. Thanks anyway. What I wrote on default.php was a simple form without any action. Just <form method="get"> and method="post". Though I tried any option I could imagine as the action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should stay there if you let the the submit go though the controller without a special redirect. It should default to the current view.
use `JHTML::_('behavior.keepalive')` in the template.

Comment: I had not any controller for it at that time. The matter is handled in another way but thank you for "JHTML::_('behavior.keepalive')".